# InstallScript : LaunchAppAndWait issues with 32 bit?

Tags: windows, dll, installshield, 32-bit, installscript

I have built a shell extension dll which is used to show right click context menu for both 64 & 32 bits. I am registering the dll in installscript during installation using LaunchAppAndWait function.

It is working fine for 64 bit machines but not for 32 bit machines.

```
if (SYSINFO.bIsWow64 ) then
    LaunchAppAndWait("", "regsvr32.exe /s " + TARGETDIR ^ "\\bin\\x64\\test.dll"  , LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);  
else
    LaunchAppAndWait("", "regsvr32.exe /s " + TARGETDIR ^ "\\bin\\test.dll"  , LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);  
endif;
```

Anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found where the problem is. By doing LongPathToQuote for the command line arg solved the problem.

```
dllPath = "/s " +TARGETDIR ^ "\\bin\\win32\\test.dll";
LongPathToQuote(dllPath,TRUE);
LaunchAppAndWait("regsvr32.exe", dllPath, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
```